# How to exclude a subfolder rule from this Rewrite condition of htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to exclude "test" subfolder from following code i.e. "www.abcwebsite.com/test"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

So when I create a subfolder in my directory it takes me back to "www.abcwebsite.com/404".

What I Want it to be like:
[www.abcwebsite.com/file.php](http://www.abcwebsite.com/file.php) > [www.abcwebsite.com/file](http://www.abcwebsite.com/file) should work 
And also
[www.abcwebsite.com/test](http://www.abcwebsite.com/test) (test being subfolder) should also work.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Guess that's because it gets externally rewritten to `/test/` first by your last rule, and then your first rule matches on it, and tries to rewrite it to `/test.php`. Your RewriteCond before that rule only checks if what was requested was not a file - which the directory isn't, so the rule is allowed to apply.

Comment: And btw., RewriteCond only affect the immediately following RewriteRule. So your _second_ rule, is currently completely independent from an conditions - not sure that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. But I was expecting an answer, rather than an explanation of the issue.
I know that the "test" folder in the directory, is being processed as "test.php" by the rule. But I'm looking for an exception rule or condition where we could exclude a directory from the rule.

Comment: I am trying to explain the issue to you, so that you can go and make an attempt to fix it. _"But I'm looking for an exception rule or condition where we could exclude a directory from the rule."_ - you have a condition already, that checks if the requested path does not match an existing _file_. So add one, that ensures the same for _folders_. The counterpart for the `-f` flag in that regard, is `-d`.